# Is there a clean way to declare a Java array with the same value for each element?

Tags: java, arrays

This isn't terribly important, but I was curious if there was a way to write a Java one liner possibly using guava or something to populate an array with elements that all have the same value.  So for example something like `Arrays.getSameElementArray(new long[12], 42L);`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes,

```
long[] arr = new long[12];
Arrays.fill(arr, 42L);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
long[] values = new long[12];
Arrays.fill(values, 42l);
```